# From URL to PHP to MySQL, how to encode and decode UTF-8?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

Let's say I want to send Unicode glyph **U+CABC** 쪼 via a web service to be saved in a database.

For example, `wget` is being used to connect to a web service:

`shell_exec("wget 'http://doit.com/testing.php?glyph=.f(0xCABC)."'")`

Where `f` is the PHP function (or functions) to convert/encode/escape the glyph U+CABC.

In testing.php, the glyph is accessed via `$_REQUEST`:

`$glyph = $_REQUEST['glyph'];`

I'd like to put it in the DB, so let's set up a query string like this:

`$query = 'INSERT INTO UTF8_TABLE (UTF8_FIELD) VALUES ('.g($glyph).')';`.

Where `g` is the PHP function (or functions) to convert the glyph into a MySQL compatible representation.

I can't seem to find what I need for the functions `f` and `g`.

For `f`, tried escaping and encoding via numerous functions, e.g. as HTML encoded UTF-8: `%EC%AA%BC`. For `g`, tried various unescaping and decoding functions, e.g. `html_entity_decode`, `utf_decode`, etc.

But no matter how I encode it, it always gets interpreted as a string of three characters **ìª¼**, which are then saved in the DB as **ìª¼** (i.e. six bytes), and not as 쪼 (i.e. three bytes).

I haven't even begun to figure out how to return the glyph via SQL `SELECT` and encoding `JSON`, but for now, would just like a straightforward way to handle UTF-8 from origin to destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$glyph = "쪼"; //or
$glyph = "\xEC\xAA\xBC";
```

This is your glyph encoded in UTF-8. The former works if you save your source code in UTF-8, the latter works in any case. To transport this in a URL, URL-encode it:

```
$url = 'http://...?glyph=' . rawurlencode($glyph);
```

On the server, PHP will automatically decode it again, so:

```
$glyph = $_GET['glyph'];
```

From there, insert it into the database the same way you would any other UTF-8 encoded text, mostly making sure the *database connection encoding* is set correctly. See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Comment: Thank you, set_charset() was the missing key. Had changed databases and didn't realize they were using latin1. Strange that the entire DB, all text fields and collations are set to UTF-8, but this extra step is needed!